# How often is Jesus quoted in the Quran?

Tags: quran, prophets, prophet-isa

I have heard it quoted that "Jesus is the most quoted prophet in the quran." I was wondering about the legitimacy of this claim, just out of plain curiosity.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE , I hope you find it interesting here to ask questions and learn more about Islam. Do browse the other questions on Jesus by clicking the jesus tag

Comment: Are you referring to how many times Jesus is mentioned by name in the Quran? or how many times Jesus's speech is recorded in the Quran?

Comment: I'm on stackoverflow, so I know how it works, I've just wandered over here from there. @Truth How many times his speech was recorded.

Comment: @JamesG. You may also [join us on Chat at the Islam room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamy) for Islam.SE

Comment: And the first most mentioned is Moses (Mossa) PBUH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer - I am not a scholar.  If you need a scholarly answer to this question, go and talk to someone more appropriate, such as the sheikh at your local masjid(mosque).**

I have found quotations from Jesus (PBUH) at the following places in The Qur'an.

- 3:49-52
- 5:72
- 5:112-116
- 19:30-33
- 43:63-64
- 61:6
- 61:14

It is possible that I have missed some, but there are certainly not as many as the earlier answer claims.

However, it seems to me to be unlikely that Jesus (PBUH) is the most quoted prophet, given that Joseph (PBUH) is quoted extensively throughout Surah 12.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

How many times is Jesus quoted in the Qur'an?
It should be noted that more or less mentioning the name of a prophet of the divine prophets in the Qur'an is not a sign of more or less importance of the position of that prophet in the sight of God, but it is an instructive point.
The name of Jesus (pbuh) is mentioned 23 times in the Holy Quran, which is:

1. Baqara, verses: 87,136,253.
2. Al-Imran, verses: 45, 52, 55, 59 and 84.
3. Women, verses: 157, 163, 171.
4. Maeda, verses: 78, 110, 112, 114, 116.
5. Reward 85.
6. Mary, 34.
7. Parties, verse 7.
8. Salinity, verse 13.
9. زخرف, آیه 63.
10. Queue, verses: 6 and 14.
    Also, the word Christ, which is one of the titles of Jesus, is mentioned 11 times in the Qur'an: Al-Imran, verse 45, Nisa, verses 157, 171 and 172, Maeda, verses 17, 72 and 75, repentance, verses 30 and 31.
    And it is mentioned in two surahs under the title of "Ibn Maryam": Mo'menun, 50, Zakhraf, 57.

Ref: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa20158